# Is it possible to run java swings through jsp without using applet?

Tags: java, jsp, applet

i am trying to run java swing program through jsp to display gui in web page but i am not getting how to run it from jsp file without using applet.anyone please help

Comment: Please note that Java Swing and Java Server Pages (JSPs) are completely different technologies that don't integrate into each other.

Comment: through applet it is possible to run swings in jsp but without applet is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without using an applet.

You can try to use an applet and then just embed it like any other HTML code inside the JSP

Comment: actually i tried with applet but the problem was displaying the continuous changing data in JLabel . it was displayed fine in applet window but it was not displaying when i embed in jsp all JLabel fields were empty